# Custom Series Shape in JFree Line chart

Tags: jfreechart, shapes, linechart

I am working to create Line chart using JFree chart libraraies. I want to change the series Shape in my line charts looks like below image. Is it possible?

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do it exactly like that, with JFreeChart "out-of-the-box", because it only lets you configure the shape (circle), outline paint and stroke, and fill paint.  But since you have the source code, you could very easily modify the code in [`LineAndShapeRenderer`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/renderer/category/LineAndShapeRenderer.html) where the shapes are drawn, and add an additional bit of code to draw the inner dark circle.  In the current release (1.0.17) the place you need to modify the code is in the drawItem() method just after [line 983](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/src-html/org/jfree/chart/renderer/category/LineAndShapeRenderer.html#line.983) (after we update the docs following the next release, this line number will be different most likely, so ignore the link after that).

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I have achieved using XYLineChart instead of LineChart. Thanks for spending your valuable time.